# Python - Define custom unittest.TextTestRunner

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, python-2.7, python-unittest

In python unittest, can how do i define a custom unittest.TextTestRunner class? I need to use the Python logger module and ensure that all logs go to the log file created by the Python logger module. Especially when exceptions and assert errors are thrown up they need to go to this log file. I need to be able to user the logger.info() and logger.warning() functions and so on.

Can anyone give me some sample code or link to sample code or steps to do so.